# Need help understanding understanding Openzeppelin contract inheritance

Tags: dapps, openzeppelin

I am playing around with the source code of a protocol named Goldfinch, and I have a few questions regarding the inheritance of openzeppelin contracts.

This is the code I've been mulling over:

[image]

1. Why is `AccessControl` termed as `AccessControlUpgradeSafe` when the `PauserPausable` contract is inheriting it?
2. I've seen other contracts do the same thing, so I'm assuming that despite the name change the contract will still compile for others. If so, why does `AccessControlUpgradeSafe` get an error saying `Identifier not found or not unique`? Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm using VScode? Or is it because the openzeppelin contract for AccessControl has been updated to solidity `0.8.0` and the `PauserPausable` contract was built using solidity `0.6.12` (I changed  `pragma solidity 0.8.0` to `pragma solidity 0.6.12` on Openzeppelin's `Access Control` contract to make it compile on VScode. I could not find the original `0.6.12` version)?
3. When I change `AccessControlUpgradeSafe` and `PausableUpgradeSafe` to `AccessControl` and `Pausable`, the error disappears, but a new one shows up on my `initializer` modifier calling it an `undeclared identifier`. Why does this happen?

Comment: sorry too many questions no one will take the time to read them all and answer them. Try to limit your questions to 1 . And openZeppelin has also discord server and forms to discuss those things

Answer (score 0):

OpenZeppelin has two sets of contracts: a regular version and an a upgradeable version. See [Using with Upgrades](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/upgradeable). The contracts are in separate repositories to avoid mixing them a causing troubles unnecessarily.

The big difference is how contracts are deployed and their initialization. The upgradable version requires a more deep knowledge about the EVM and and upgradable contracts in general, so it is for more advanced users.